# Seeing if all rows in selection match criteria

Tags: sql, azure-stream-analytics

First, let me preface this by saying that I'm terrible at SQL, so my apologies.

Here's what I need to achieve.

I have data in a table, let's just say it looks like:

| timestamp | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-14T100:00:01.000Z | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-04-14T100:00:02.000Z | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-04-14T100:00:03.000Z | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-04-14T100:00:04.000Z | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-04-14T100:00:05.000Z | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-04-14T100:00:06.000Z | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I'm working with some IOT data, that comes in at lets say roughly 1 second intervals. It won't always be exaxtly 1 second.

I'd like to pull out all the records from the current time stamp and say 2 seconds previous. So, in this case, for arguments sake, let's start from 2021-04-14:00:00:04.

The query should pull out the first 3 queries where the values are all above 0. It would look something like:

```
   Select * from table 
      WHERE DateAdd(seconds, -3, "2021-04-14T00:00:03) AND
      value 1 > 0 AND value2 > 0 AND value3 > 0
```

Which is fine, and will return the first three rows. What I'm getting hung up on is that I want a way to determine if ALL the rows returned match the criteria.

So, if the same query was appended to start from 06:

```
   Select * from table 
      WHERE DateAdd(seconds, -3, "2021-04-14T00:00:06) AND
      value 1 > 0 AND value2 > 0 AND value3 > 0
```

It would only return 2 rows instead of 3. I'm not sure how to determine that there were rows in the middle that weren't included, other than doing another query that was effectively the reverse and then comparing a count.

I guess I'm just looking for a smarter way to do this.

Any and all advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: WHERE DateAdd(seconds, -3, "2021-04-14T00:00:06) .. What is this supposed to do? There's no condition here

Comment: sorry... should have added a BETWEEN 0 AND 3 after it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understood you, but you can use ORDER BY and TOP

```
SELECT TOP 3 t.* FROM (
  Select s.* from table s
  WHERE s.timestamp < <<YourTargetDateHere>>
    AND s.value1 > 0 AND s.value2 > 0 AND s.value3 > 0
  ORDER BY s.timestamp DESC) t
```

This will first filter only records that match all criteria, and then choose the top 3 based on descending order of your date column.

Comment: Thanks, that's not what I need unfortunately. I obviously did a poor job explaining. But basically I need to know that all the rows that are, in this case, 3 seconds back, match the criteria.